# React highlighting query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, search

I'm making an suggestions component and I need to highlight part of suggestion that is matching the query (just like duckduck.go does).

 
**Current Logic**:

```
function Highlight({ text = '', highlight = '' }) {
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, 'gi');
  const split = text.split(regex);
  return (
    <span>
      {split
        .filter((current) => current)
        .map((current, i) => (regex.test(current) ? <span key={i}>{current}</span> : <em>key={i}>{current}</em>))}
    </span>
  );
}
```

e.g  
**Suggestions**: United States, United Airlines 
**Query**: United <== highlighting *United* States / *United* Airlines ##   works fine 
**Query**: United St <== highlighting only *United St*ates / United Airlines ## does't work fine 
**Expecting**: United St ==> *United St*ates & *United* Airlines 
**Expecting**: nited St ==> United *St*ates & United Airlines 
**Expecting**: Unit St ==> *Unit*ed *St*ates & United Airlines

Comment: Could you please explain what behavior you need to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

**I just wrote a function That matches your requirements**

Please Note that this function is Case Sensitive
TypeScript

```
const highLight = (
  query: string, // The Query
  suggestion: string, // The Suggestion
  tag: string = "strong"
): string => {
  const querySplit = query.split(" ");
  const suggestionSplit = suggestion.split(" ");

  let res: string = "";
  let matchFullFirst = false; // This Variable track if the first Word is a complete match 

  for (let i = 0; i < querySplit.length && i < suggestionSplit.length; i++) {
    if (suggestionSplit[i].startsWith(querySplit[i])) {
      if (i == 0 && suggestionSplit[i].length === querySplit[i].length) {
        matchFullFirst = true;
      }

      res += ` <${tag}>${querySplit[i]}</${tag}>${suggestionSplit[i].slice(
        querySplit[i].length
      )}`;
      continue;
    }

    if (matchFullFirst) {
      res += suggestion.slice(querySplit[0].length);
      break;
    }
    res = suggestion;
    break;
  }
  return res;
};
```

Javascript

```
  const highLight = (query, suggestion, tag = "strong") => {
  const querySplit = query.split(" ");
  const suggestionSplit = suggestion.split(" ");

  let res = "";
  let matchFullFirst = false;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < querySplit.length && i < suggestionSplit.length; i++) {
    if (suggestionSplit[i].startsWith(querySplit[i])) {
      if (i == 0 && suggestionSplit[i].length === querySplit[i].length) {
        matchFullFirst = true;
      }

      res += ` <${tag}>${querySplit[i]}</${tag}>${suggestionSplit[i].slice(
        querySplit[i].length
      )}`;
      continue;
    }

    if (matchFullFirst) {
      res += suggestion.slice(querySplit[0].length);
      break;
    }
    res = suggestion;
    break;
  }
  return res;
};
```

Comment: `United St` => highlights only '**United St**ates'  `Nited States` => doesn't highlight anything

Comment: Please check the question again, The function matches all the expectations as you mentioned in the question,

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion, can you please edit the expectations and make them bold instead of italic, as it is confusing

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. 
 
**Change**:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`(${highlight})`, 'gi');
```

to

```
const regex = new RegExp(
    `\\b(${escapeRegExp(phrase)
      .trim()
      .split(' ')
      .filter((t) => t)
      .join('|')})`,
    'gi'
  );

 1. (\\b(${escapeRegExp(phrase).trim().split(' ').filter((t) =>
    t).join('|')})`,'gi');                                     ===> left side must match

 2.  (${escapeRegExp(phrase).trim().split(' ').filter((t) =>
    t).join('|')})\\b`,'gi');                                  ===> right side must match 

 3. (\\b(${escapeRegExp(phrase).trim().split(' ').filter((t) =>
    t).join('|')})\\b`,'gi');                                  ===> both sides must match

 4. ((${escapeRegExp(phrase).trim().split(' ').filter((t) =>
    t).join('|')})`,'gi');                                     ===> neither side has to match
```